# PyGame not quitting after pygame.quit() and sys.exit(0) are called

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pygame

I was doing some testing with the Pygame module, however when I quit the program using the following piece of code, the Pygame launcher application ([Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvSIn.png)) does not quit after the I close the window (It required force quit). Is there a way to fix this?

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

# Code for creating window surface, putting things on it, etc.

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
```

I tried to look it up, but none of the offered solutions work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's a *Pygame launcher application*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out an alternative. Although this uses the OS module (and a protected method which I personally recommend against), it does the job pretty well.

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        os._exit(0) # Forcibly exit the program
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's gonna work but you better try it. I add some variable for while loop

```
somevariable = True
while somevariable == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            somevariable = False

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: It still didn't work... ;(  I'll explain the question better.